# Code needs to group rows below active cell

Tags: excel, rows, vba

Have a worksheet with 1000+ rows with a pattern of text on first row and then have 3 blank rows. I need to copy the text from column B first row down through the next 3 rows. Then I need to designate those 3 rows as a group of the initial row. I have got the below code to work for the first two lines, but then it stops on line 3, I get a Compile error: Syntax error. I know from having recorded the initial macro from doing the steps that the beginning of line 3, Rows, is needed, but can't seem to find the right syntax to tell the system that the rows to be grouped are the next 3.

Edit:
Added missing code sample.

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0)), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0)).Select
Rows(ActiveCell.Row 1,ActiveCell.Row 3).Select
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(3, -1)).Activate
Selection.Rows.Group
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0)).Select
```

Second Edit:
Added in recorded macro from doing the keystrokes to accomplish the grouping of the next 3 rows. Starting with having just copied the first row to the other 3 rows, the keystrokes were: 1 down, Shift/Space, Shift/2 down, Alt/dgg.
Macro:

```
Rows("1037:1039").Select
Range("A1039").Activate
Selection.Rows.Group
```

Comment: can you show us the code that's causing the error, or at least provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

From Recording a macro with "Use Relative References" activated from the Developer tab's Code section, I recorded a working model to solve my issue. This marco does the following:
 - copies the active cell content down 3 rows
 - selects the entire 3 rows
 - makes those 3 rows a group of the initial row
 - goes to the next primary row of the next grouping

###########  Initial Script from Recorded Macro     ############################

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A4"), Type:=xlFillDefault
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A4").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Activate
Selection.Rows.Group
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

In testing the resulting macro, I found an issue which was fixed by eliminating the 4th line. So the successful macro code is listed below:

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Final Script
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A4"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A4").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Rows.Group
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1).Range("A1").Select